# ACCESS_DENIED ao consumir API Googles Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Tentando fazer uma Geolocalização entre CEP, tenho esse código, baixado

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Calcular distancia entre cidades (mapas e rotas)</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Parâmetro sensor é utilizado somente em dispositivos com GPS -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CalculaDistancia() {
            $('#litResultado').html('Aguarde...');
            //Instanciar o DistanceMatrixService
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            //executar o DistanceMatrixService
            service.getDistanceMatrix(
              {
                  //Origem
                  origins: [$("#txtOrigem").val()],
                  //Destino
                  destinations: [$("#txtDestino").val()],
                  //Modo (DRIVING | WALKING | BICYCLING)
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                  //Sistema de medida (METRIC | IMPERIAL)
                  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
                  //Vai chamar o callback
              }, callback);
        }
        //Tratar o retorno do DistanceMatrixService
        function callback(response, status) {
            //Verificar o Status
            if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
                //Se o status não for "OK"
                $('#litResultado').html(status);
            else {
                //Se o status for OK
                //Endereço de origem = response.originAddresses
                //Endereço de destino = response.destinationAddresses
                //Distância = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
                //Duração = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
                $('#litResultado').html("<strong>Origem</strong>: " + response.originAddresses +
                    "<br /><strong>Destino:</strong> " + response.destinationAddresses +
                    "<br /><strong>Distância</strong>: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text +
                    " <br /><strong>Duração</strong>: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
                    );
                //Atualizar o mapa
                $("#map").attr("src", "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + response.originAddresses + "&daddr=" + response.destinationAddresses + "&output=embed");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="txtOrigem"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de origem</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" id="txtOrigem" class="field" style="width: 400px" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="txtDestino"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de destino</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" style="width: 400px" class="field" id="txtDestino" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Calcular dist&acirc;ncia" onclick="CalculaDistancia()" class="btnNew" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div><span id="litResultado">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

Sempre que jogo dois CEP's, recebo um `ACCES_DENIED`. Acredito que seja o parâmetro **sensor**. Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa utilizar uma chave de API para fazer a chamada ao serviço do Google Maps. Para isso, você precisa se cadastrar.

A mensagem de erro que aparece é a seguinte:

Distance Matrix Service: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Na mensagem de erro tem um link com mais explicações:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key